# Shiro subject on HttpSession

Tags: shiro, httpsession, subject

I'm using Shiro on my application layer which is served trough web requests. I think ***SecurityUtils.getSubject*** won't work as expected as I want to save the current subject through different requests, and I don't want to use Shiro Web utils, because I would like to dettach my Application Layer from the way it is served( I will later build a GUI to access it ).

So, can I, for example, return from my application layer the Subject instance, to be saved by the client in an ***HttpSession*** or whenever it wants, and retrieve it at a later time to avoid having to re-authenticate it?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do this is to keep the subject's sessionId in the client and acquiring the subject again via:

```
Subject requestSubject = new Subject.Builder().sessionId(sessionId).buildSubject();
```

Am I right?